# IntelliJ null check warnings

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, jetbrains-ide

I often have code like this:

```
protected @Nullable Value value;

public boolean hasValue() { return value != null; }
```

the problem with this is that when I do null checks like so:

```
if (!hasValue()) throw...
return value.toString();
```

then IntelliJ will warn me about a possible NPE

whereas

```
if (value != null) throw...
return value.toString();
```

avoids this warning.

is there a way to decorate my `hasValue()` method so that IntelliJ knows it does a null check? and won't display the warning?

Comment: Is the `hasValue` really that simple?

Comment: what about the `@suppresswarnings( nullcheck )` annotation ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes

Comment: What's the version of Intellij-Idea that you use? My 14th version doesn't show me this warning (in this particular case).

Comment: @Andremoniy It is the 2016.3.4. Oh.. I see the problem I use `@Nullable` to decorate the value field - if I removed that, it goes away.

Comment: You can use @NotNull to indicate that a parameter should never be null. IntelliJ can add bytecode verification to your method in these cases.

Comment: What is `@Nullable?` From which package?

Comment: @Andremoniy `package org.jetbrains.annotations;` I like to decorate the fields that are set by the constructors with `@Nullable/@NotNull

Comment: If you're going to throw anyway why go through this rigamarole instead of just letting the NPE go? if it's a violation of contract, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: @pvg better exception message, easily recognizable what happened in the logs (in this case, I don't always do that for all checks - but in this case it `hasValue()` is kind of like an API method)

Comment: Hardly seems worth the lines of ceremony. Plus if it's happening, it's actually a bug right? so it's not like some condition that requires its own information message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intellij-Jetbrains is very clever IDE and itself suggests you way for solving many problems.

Look at screenshot below. It suggests your five ways for removing this warning:

1) add `assert value != null`;

2) replace return statement with `return value != null ? value.toString() : null;`

3) surround with

```
    if (value != null) {
        return value.toString();
    }
```

4) suppress inspection for this particular statement by adding commentary:

```
//noinspection ConstantConditions
return value.toString();
```

5) add at least, as earlier @ochi suggested use `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")` annotation which can be used for method or for whole class.

To invoke this context menu use shortcut keys `Alt+Enter` (I think they are common for all OS).

[image]

Comment: All of these techiques indeed prevent IntelliJ from issuing the warning.  However, none of them answers the original question of ensuring that "IntelliJ knows it [hasValue] does a null check".  
Some other tools have more sophisticated code analysis and support a postcondition annotation [`@EnsuresNonNullIf`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/EnsuresNonNullIf.html) that does what the original poster asked -- but unfortunately IntelliJ currently does not.