# Annotate method as null checking for a variable

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ and I want to remove a warning that appears but in theory shouldn't, but lint doesn't analyse my code far enough to realize it.

I have a class with two methods and a variable like this:

```
@Nullable Object object;

boolean isObjectNotNull() {
    return object != null;
}
```

Then in another class I do:

```
if (class.isObjectNotNull() {
    Object object = class.object.isEnabled();
}
```

And I get a null check warning on `isEnabled` call because `object` is annotated as nullable, but it was check before for null and it turned out not to be.

I tried using the `@Contract` annotation but it's no help.

The idea is very basic and probably too much effort for what it's worth, but I want to know if it's doable in an easy way.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126828/intellij-null-check-warnings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ null check warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126828/intellij-null-check-warnings)

Comment: @AJNeufeld Yes it's a duplicate, but I found that I could use `@EnsuresNonNullIf(expression="this.object", result=true)` with a particular library. Is this supported by IntelliJ?

Comment: According to a comment (Feb 10th, 2017) by [mernst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173852/mernst) in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42127085/3690024) for the question that this is a duplicate of: "_but unfortunately IntelliJ currently does not._".  But it is almost a year later, so ... perhaps?  If your research shows yes, then add an answer to that question.

Comment: Still not supported it seems, I've tried it.